# Как зарегистрироваться на сайте через госуслуги

Tags: uuid, есиа, госуслуги

Пытаюсь осуществить регистрацию на сайте через Госуслуги.
Использую для этих целей "МЕТОДИЧЕСКИЕ РЕКОМЕНДАЦИИ ПО ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЮ ЕСИА".https://digital.gov.ru/ru/documents/6186/
Застрял на пункте "В.2.3 Получение авторизационного кода (v2/ac)".

```
<?php
$client_secret = "";
    $client_id = "MYTEST";
    $scope = "openid";
    $timestamp = date('Y.m.d H:i:s O');
    $state = uniqid();
    $redirect_uri = "https://my-test.ru/login/esia";

    $client_secret = urlencode($client_id.$scope.$timestamp.$state.$redirect_uri);

$client_certificate_hash = "";
$response_type = "code";
$access_type = "online";

$url = "https://esia-portal1.test.gosuslugi.ru/aas/oauth2/v2/ac?".
                                "client_secret=".$client_secret.
                                "&client_id=".$client_id.
                                "&scope=".$scope.
                                "&timestamp=".$timestamp.
                                "&state=".$state.
                                "&redirect_uri=".$redirect_uri.
                                "&client_certificate_hash=".$client_certificate_hash.
                                "&response_type=".$response_type.
                                "&access_type=".$access_type;
?>
                                
<a href="<?=$url;?>"><?=$url?></a><br>
```

Может ли кто ни будь подсказать как правильно получить "client_certificate_hash"?
Правильно ли я понял как получается "state" ?
Есть ли какие ни будь ошибки в коде?
Возможно существует какой ни будь тотуреаль?

p.s. Поддержка проста скидывает ссылку на документацию. ( И с ними ругаться просто бесполезно.(
p.s2. Опасаюсь использовать готовые решения с github, т.к. выходит что мы получаем доступ к секретным данным клиента. И не хотелось бы опозорить наши Госуслуги.(

Comment: А вы вообще читали эту документацию? Вроде там про client_certificate_hash все четко написано. Берете утилиту (ссылка на нее есть в документации), скармливаете ей свой сертификат, получаете хэш.
А в формировании client_secret у вас отсутствуют шаги 2) и 3) из описанного там алгоритма. Есть только 1) и зачем-то url encode, вместо требуемого в шаге 4) base64

Comment: Я не спорю, что не смог разобраться с документацией. Но и вы должны согласится со мной. Для аналогичных задач, документация по регистрации через VK, Яндекс и т.п. Написана гораздо лучше, с примерами кода.

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, а вы не подскажете, как именно через php. Cделать "подписать полученную строку с использованием алгоритма подписания  data hash" ?  Или это делается только через Криптопро?

Comment: Не подскажу. :( Термин "алгоритм подписания data hash" даже не гуглится, что именно тут имели в виду авторы документации - неясно.