# подписать полученную строку с использованием алгоритма подписания data hash

Tags: php, криптопро

Требуется "подписать полученную строку с использованием алгоритма подписания  data  hash"
Как это реализовать через PHP? Или это делается только через Криптопро?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как зарегистрироваться на сайте через госуслуги](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1472730/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%81%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b8)